High "System"/CcUnpinRepinnedBcb CPU usage
I'm seeing unexpectedly high CPU usage by the "System" process (ntoskrnl.exe).
It's up to ~10% total CPU usage at idle.
Using Process Explorer, I can see this is almost entirely attributed to ntoskrnl.exe!CcUnpinRepinnedBcb+0x370 in System process.
Problem is, this is where I'm stuck. I would like to find out what is causing this issue as it keeps my laptop constantly boosting its CPU, drawing power, running its fan, etc.
This is with a recently cleanly installed Win 11 Pro on a Ryzen 7 7840HS + 32GB laptop.
I've got a lot of devices connected, and keep reading that driver conflicts may cause this behavior. However, I don't know how to analyze that.
I only know a clumsy workaround so far:

A reboot mitigates for a while, but eventually that function consumes unexpectedly many cycles again

I tried the following troubleshooting:

tried using RAMMap to find what is calling that function, but I fail to even figure out what memory address to look at


ProcessExplorer gives me the Start Address as ntoskrnl.exe!CcUnpinRepinnedBcb+0x370, but nowhere can I find the address of ntoskrnl or said function itself
In RAMMap, neither System nor ntoskrnl.exe show up as a Physical Pages entry at all


I've disconnected all external devices (USB-C dock with mouse, kb, webcam, microphone, DAC; TB3 eGPU), but the high CPU usage remains (though IF it is caused by a bad driver, it could be one of the laptop's built-in components)
Updated Windows and all drivers to what is available from either Windows Update or the respective vendor

In short: I don't know what to look for.
A similar issue has been reported at
High "System" CPU usage; unaccounted for Memory usage
But there is no answer yet either.

Some introductory info: Cc is the NT cache manager subsystem, used by filesystems to cache file data in RAM. A BCB is a buffer control block describing a part of a file mapped to the cache somewhere in memory. CcUnpinRepinnedBcb is a function that a filesystem driver would call to tell the kernel it no longer needs a particular BCB so the cache manager can get rid of it. (None of this of course tells you which filesystem, what file, or which process is triggering all that churn, that's why it's not an answer.)

This is happening to me too on my framework 13 laptop, also a ryzen system though 7840u instead of hs. It's frustrating as it makes the system laggy, and keeps the cpu pinned at higher frequencies which spins up the fans and reduces battery life. Confusingly the numbers reported in task manager are higher than what process explorer sees. Either way I'm out of ideas on how to troubleshoot further..

Happens to me as well, similar specs. AMD processor Ryzen 9 8945HS.

Are y'all using WSL? I use it daily and am wondering if that's the common denominator (along with Ryzen)

I posted a detailed answer to this but a moderator deleted it. This is caused by a bug in the current version of the AMD Radeon GPU driver for the integrated GPUs. You can read more here. What you'll want to do is disable your integrated GPU (if you're not using it) then run the official AMD Cleanup Utility which will uninstall the buggy driver. If you need the integrated GPU, downgrade to drivers 23.10 or earlier, or wait until AMD releases a fix.

Also seeing this, and its a pretty fresh Windows 11 install (after getting annoyed with a similar high CPU usage by System on the previous install...)

Having the same issue on my Framework 16 with 23.40.18.02 AMD drivers. I need iGPU, and it's not something I should do on a computer to get it working. I posted a topic on the Framework forums.

According to this community post, the issue was solved in the AMD Adrenalin 24.7.1 and above.
I can confirm that I installed Adrenalin 24.8.1 and the issue is not present anymore.

That post seems to be largely focused around a memory leak. I don't see any reference to CPU usage

@John yeah, I didn't have a memory leak, but maybe they are related as other people also pointed to similar discussions with a memory leak. Point is, I installed the Adrenalin 24.8.1 and the CPU usage is gone.
